# connection error between sql and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

i have created that table on my sql server :

```
create table Empolyee(
ESSN int not null,
EFirstName varchar(20) not null ,
ELastName varchar(20) not null,
EJob varchar(20),
EBDate date,
ESalary int,

primary key(ESSN));
```

and in C# i try to add data to database using that code :

```
SqlConnection sqc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Empolyee VALUES (@ESSN,@EFirstName,@ELastName,@EJob,@EBDate,@ESalary)", sqc);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ESSN", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@EFirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ELastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@EJob", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@EBDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = maskedTextBox1.Text;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ESalary", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox5.Text;

        // open connection
        sqc.Open();
        // excute the command
        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // close connection
        sqc.Close();
```

i get that error when i run : Object reference not set to an instance of an object or System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: Please tell us **exactly where** you get that error.

Comment: When doing the Insert you don't need a DataAdapter object or DataSet try looking at using a dataReader

Comment: da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you haven't assigned anything to `da.InsertCommand` - instead you have put an `INSERT` command into `da.SelectCommand`... just change all references from `da.SelectCommand` to `da.InsertCommand` in the code you show in your question:

```
    da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Empolyee VALUES (@ESSN,@EFirstName,@ELastName,@EJob,@EBDate,@ESalary)", sqc);
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ESSN", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@EFirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ELastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@EJob", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@EBDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = maskedTextBox1.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ESalary", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox5.Text;
```

BTW you don't need any `SqlDataAdapter` or `DataSet` to execute an `INSERT` - it can be done with `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` only.

Comment: OH MY GOSH , i can`t belive how come i choose selectcommand , thanks a lot , it works now

Comment: @R.Vector you are welcome :-) please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that is of help (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2):

you are executing the following line:

```
  da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

but you are init SelectCommand

Try to replace the following code:

```
da.InsertCommand= new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Empolyee VALUES (@ESSN,@EFirstName,@ELastName,@EJob,@EBDate,@ESalary)", sqc);
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ESSN", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@EFirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ELastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@EJob", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@EBDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = maskedTextBox1.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ESalary", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox5.Text;
```